# Alternate two colour in concentric circles

Tags: plotting, graphics, color

This code gives me two sets of concentric circles with respective radii of `2n` and `2n-1`:

```
With[{n = 5}, Show[Graphics[
({{Circle[{0, 0}, 2*#1]}, {Circle[{0, 0}, 
     2*#1 - 1]}} & ) /@ Range[n]], Axes -> True]]
```

[image]

I would like alternating circles to be red and blue. I don't want to change anything else. But I can't figure out where to insert a `PlotStyle` instruction...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
With[{n = 5}, Graphics[{{Red, Circle[{0, 0}, 2*#1]}, Blue, {Circle[{0, 0}, 2*#1 - 1]}} &/@
  Range[n], Axes -> True]]
```

[image]

Comment: Appreciated. Feeling a bit of muppet. Can't accept for 8 mins, but will then do so :-)

Comment: @RichardBurke-Ward, it happens to all of us:)

Answer (score 3):

kglr's solution is what I would have done in old *Mathematica*. Nowadays, I would use `Riffle[]`:

```
With[{n = 5}, 
     Graphics[Riffle[Flatten[{Circle[{0, 0}, 2 #1 - 1], Circle[{0, 0}, 2 #1]} & /@ 
                             Range[n]], {Blue, Red}, {1, -2, 2}],
              Axes -> True]]
```

[image: concentric circles with alternating colors]

Answer (score 3):

```
With[{n = 5},
 Graphics[
  Table[{If[OddQ[i], Blue, Red], Circle[{0, 0}, i]}, {i, n * 2}],
  Axes -> True]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Using `BlockMap`:

```
With[{n = 5}, 
Graphics[
BlockMap[{If[OddQ[#[[1]]], Blue, Red], Circle[{0, 0}, #[[1]]]} &, 
Range[2 n], 1], Axes -> True]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

table driven

```
With[{n = 5},
    Graphics[Table[{<|True -> Blue, False -> Red|>[OddQ[i]], Circle[{0, 0}, i]}, {i, n * 2}], Axes -> True]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

A few variations:

```
Clear["Global`*"];
n = 5;

c1 = {If[OddQ[#], Blue, Red], Circle[{0, 0}, #]} & /@ Range[2 n];

c2 = Array[{Red, Circle[{0, 0}, 2 #], Blue, 
    Circle[{0, 0}, 2 # - 1]} &, {n}];

c3 = MapIndexed[{If[OddQ[First@#2], Blue, Red], Circle[{0, 0}, #1]} &,
   Range[2 n]];

c4 = MapThread[{#1, Circle[{0, 0}, #2]} &
  , {Sequence @@@ ConstantArray[{Blue, Red}, n]
   , Range[2 n]
   }
  ];

c5 = FoldPairList[{{If[OddQ[#1], Blue, Red], 
     Circle[{0, 0}, #1]}, #2} &, Range[2 n]];
```

---

```
Graphics[#, Axes -> True] & /@ {c1, c2, c3, c4, c5}

(* desired output x5 *)
```